# SCSS declaring Mixins with breakpoints

Tags: sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

Is it possible to use SCSS to write Mixins that also change properties based on media queries. Take this that changes the font-size and line-height based on breakpoint declaration map. Is this possible?

```
$breakpoints: (
  min: 312px,
  mid: 680px,
  max: 1020px,
);

@mixin fontsize($size) {
  @if ($size == "xsmall") {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    @media only screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, "mid")) {
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, "max")) {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 26px;
    }
  }
}

p {
  @include fontsize("xsmall");
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

This should mean that a paragraph has a variable font size and line height. But before refactoring vast quantities of css variables I wanted to know if this would actually work?

From what I can see it does work but in terms of correct syntax and browser compatibility is this approach correct?

https://codepen.io/Walrus117/pen/RwdKmoX

Comment: Yes this is totally fine. Just so you know, all browsers other than IE accept media queries, there is no need to write `@media only screen` anymore unless you specifically must support IE. The `only` keyword was to make browsers without media query support ignore the query. In 2024 you can simply write `@media screen and ( ... )` Also, with the new version of sass (16+), you should be using modules explicitly. Support for the way you write things like the built in map-get() function will be deprecated. Instead write `@use sass:map` at top of file and then `map.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is totally fine.

Taking the web projects I have participated in as my sample, I conclude that wrapping `@media` queries in specialized `@mixin`s is a well established approach to UI responsiveness in web apps utilizing SASS / SCSS.

SASS handles the nesting when compiling it and produces syntactically valid CSS.
You can see what it outputs by pasting your snippet into https://www.sassmeister.com/:

```css
p {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {
  p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
}
```

Regarding browser compatibility of CSS3 Media Queries: `@media` is supported by all major browsers [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

If you only target browsers that support custom css variables (i.e. all modern browsers, no IE [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-variables)), you might want to also explore the possibilities of having responsive variables:
(Disclaimer: I haven't tried that out yet in any real project. It may well be that this results in a rather inflexible mess)

```
$mid: 680px;
$max: 1020px;
:root {
  --responsive-font-size-sm: 13px;
  --responsive-line-height-sm: 18px;
  @media only screen and (min-width: $mid) {
    --responsive-font-size-sm: 15px;
    --responsive-line-height-sm: 20px;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: $max) {
    --responsive-font-size-sm: 18px;
    --responsive-line-height-sm: 26px;
  }
}

p {
  font-size: var(--responsive-font-size-sm);
  line-height: var(--responsive-line-height-sm);
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful. Your custom css variables suggestion is my current approach and it has become an inflexible mess. The sass route has reduced the amount of clutter by over three quarters already and I haven't finished refactoring everything yet.